# Agrupar y concatenar columnas de mas de una fila en una Javascript, como STUFF en SQL

Tags: javascript

```
    //VALORES ACTUALES
{Posicion: 0, Texto: "M1", Elemento: "Cr", Rango: "1.00-1.50"}
{Posicion: 0, Texto: "M1", Elemento: "Mo", Rango: "0.30-0.65"}
{Posicion: 1, Texto: "M2", Elemento: "Cr", Rango: "1.23-1.50"}
{Posicion: 1, Texto: "M2", Elemento: "Nb", Rango: "1.00-1.23"}
{Posicion: 1, Texto: "M2", Elemento: "V", Rango: "0.45-1.50"}
{Posicion: 2, Texto: "M3", Elemento: "Cr", Rango: "1.00-1.50"}

//VALORES DESEADOS
{Posicion: 0, Texto: "M1", Elemento: "Cr,Mo", Rango: "1.00-1.50,0.30-0.65"}
{Posicion: 2, Texto: "M2", Elemento: "Cr,Nb,V", Rango: "1.23-1.50,1.00-1.23,0.45-1.50"}
{Posicion: 3, Texto: "M3", Elemento: "Cr", Rango: "1.00-1.50"}

//VALORES DE ALEANTES
    {AleanteID: 1, Elemento: "Cr,Mo", Rango: "1.00-1.50,0.30-0.65"}
    {AleanteID: 2, Elemento: "Cr,Mo,V", Rango: "8.00-9.50,0.85-1.05,0.15-0.30"}
```

aun con lo que tengo no logro obtener el resultado deseado:

```
 var min = 0, max = 0;
var result = [];
if (dataElementos.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < dataElementos.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < aleantes.length; j++) {
            //if (dataElementos[i].Posicion == i) {
                if (dataElementos[i].Elemento == aleantes[j].Elemento) {
                    min = parseFloat(aleantes[j].Rango.split("-")[0]).toFixed(2);
                    max = parseFloat(aleantes[j].Rango.split("-")[1]).toFixed(2);
                    if (parseFloat(dataElementos[i].Valor).toFixed(2) >= min && parseFloat(dataElementos[i].Valor).toFixed(2) <= max) {
                        result.push({ Posicion: i, Texto: dataElementos[i].Text, Elemento: dataElementos[i].Elemento, Valor: dataElementos[i].Valor});
                    }                       
                }
            //}                
        }
    }
}
return result;
```

Espero si alguien me puede orientar a obtener el resultado deseado (parecido al STUFF de SQL Server) de antemano gracias.

Comment: En donde declaras la variable `aleantes`?

Comment: Perdón amigo, aleantes es una lista traida de BD, y su formato es `{AleanteID: 1, Elemento: "Cr,Mo", Rango: "1.00-1.50,0.30-0.65"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener el resultado deseado,  solamente necesitas un `for` asi:

```js
var dataElementos = [{Posicion: 0, Texto: "M1", Elemento: "Cr", Rango: "1.00-1.50"},
{Posicion: 0, Texto: "M1", Elemento: "Mo", Rango: "0.30-0.65"},
{Posicion: 1, Texto: "M2", Elemento: "Cr", Rango: "1.23-1.50"},
{Posicion: 1, Texto: "M2", Elemento: "Nb", Rango: "1.00-1.23"},
{Posicion: 1, Texto: "M2", Elemento: "V", Rango: "0.45-1.50"},
{Posicion: 2, Texto: "M3", Elemento: "Cr", Rango: "1.00-1.50"}];

var result = [dataElementos[0]];
var j = 0;
if (dataElementos.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 1; i < dataElementos.length; i++) {            
        if (dataElementos[i].Texto == result[j].Texto) {
            result[j].Elemento = result[j].Elemento + ',' + dataElementos[i].Elemento;
            result[j].Rango = result[j].Rango + ',' + dataElementos[i].Rango;
        } else {
            result.push(dataElementos[i]);
            j++;              
        }
    }
    
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Excelente es a lo que quería llegar, te lo agradezco saludos.